# Using SWIG to convert C++ char* as char[] in Java instead of String

Tags: c++, swig

I am attempting to wrap the following C++ function with Java:

```
char* MyClass::to_cstring();
```

This output of this function is returned as a Java String object.  I would like it to return as a `char[]` Java array.  I am currently using "typemaps.i" and "std_string.i".  Is there a way to override the behavior such that std::string is still returned as a Java `String`, but `char*` is returned as a Java char array?

How about using Java `byte[]` instead of `char[]` so there is not need to worry about translating between 8-bit C++ chars and Java's 16-bit Unicode?

Comment: At the very least, that would have to be a `byte[]` in Java. Java's `char` is a UTF-16 code unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you'll need to replace the default SWIG supplied typemaps with one of your own. The simplest way to do this requires just writing some Java "glue":

```
%module test

%typemap(jstype) char *to_cstring() "byte[]";
%typemap(javaout) char *to_cstring() {
  return $jnicall.getBytes();
}

%inline %{
char *to_cstring() {
  static char ret[] = "hello world";
  return ret;
}
%}
```

Does exactly what you want by calling `getBytes()` behind the scenes on the default returned `String`.

You can also do this with some JNI of your own to return it as a byte array all the way through from your native code:

```
%module test

%typemap(jstype) char *to_cstring() "byte[]";
%typemap(jtype) char *to_cstring() "byte[]";
%typemap(javaout) char *to_cstring() {
  return $jnicall;
}
%typemap(jni) char *to_cstring() "jbyteArray";
%typemap(out) char *to_cstring() {
  const size_t len = strlen($1);
  $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, len);
  // TODO: check that this succeeded
  JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, len, (const jbyte*)$1);
}

%inline %{
char *to_cstring() {
  static char ret[] = "hello world";
  return ret;
}
%}
```

The difference here being that the mapping to `byte[]` happens in the generated JNI, not in the Java glue. The glue now just proxies directly to the JNI unchanged.

I was able to test and verify these typemaps with the following Java:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    byte[] ret = test.to_cstring();
    System.out.println(ret.length);
    System.out.println((char)ret[0]);
  }
}
```

In both these examples the typemaps match on both the return type (`char *`) and the function `to_cstring()`. You can adjust this typemap matching to be more or less selective. It currently doesn't change most normal usage, you can also use `%apply` to copy the typemap to other cases which don't exactly match.