# Using swig, how do I return a byte array (byte[]) from a swigged method that returns an array of chars?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm using swig and in my Java class, I have this:

```
public MyClass {
   private void loadData() {
        byte[] data = NativeClass.getDataBytes();
   }
}
```

In my native code, I have this class:

```
class NativeClass
{
public:
    char *getDataBytes();
};
```

How do I configure my swig file so that `NativeClass.getData()` will return the expected data as a byte array?

Comment: With the first part of this answer you should be able to write the appropriate SWIG typemaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11584600/168175

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17638891/168175 but I'm not voting to close as such unless you're happy for me to do so given my conflict of interest.

Comment: @Flexo Thanks for looking.  That is the answer that I'm looking for!  However, the question is different.  My question really is simply about how to return a byte array from a swigged function.  The other question asks how to return a char array.  And I think, if that question was properly worded, I would have found that answer when I searched for it.   Still, I'd be happy to delete my question if other people think it's not useful.

Comment: I think they were just confused about byte vs char in Java when they asked it. I'm going to close this as a duplicate, in doing so it'll help others find the same question/answer in the future based on your phrasing. If you disagree I'm happy to reopen it though, but I think that's the best state for it.

Comment: That's fine. Thank you for your inputs.